# Are digestive enzymes a must in whey supplements?

Tags: protein-shakes, resistancetraining, whey

I have come across strong opinions which suggest that whey supplements without digestive enzymes are waste. The counter argument that our body has all necessary enzymes to digest whey and added enzymes may harm is also very strong on internet.

My question is If I am using whey to fill the protein gap in my diet and post workout recovery what should i use whey with enzymes or whey without enzymes?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Whey is a byproduct of milk after it's been curdled and strained to form cheese. So taking whey is not much different than drinking milk. If you can digest milk (I.E. not lactose intolerant), then you can digest whey.

If you are lactose intolerant, then you probably would need to take a Lactaid or something to digest it. Though, a better alternative would be to just not take it. There are plant and egg based supplements that can be bought instead of whey. Or fulfill your protein needs through regular diet over supplementation.